# Create a Menu in a non-existent module in Everhest

Tags: module, joomla, sliding

I'm currently using the [Everhest](http://www.globbersthemes.com/demo/everhest/) Joomla template for one of my websites.

I can't figure how I can build the menu on top of the scrolling images. The objective would be to have an equal menu, even with the sliding text when you put your mouse in the "Joomla Overview".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I understand what you need now. Some template developers will hard code menus in to their templates in order to maintain the look of the original template. There are several ways to do this, but the most common way I have seen it done is by using a specific menu name - typically mainmenu. You don't have to put it in a module position, you just name the menu that you want to show up there the proper name.

If you want to post the code for index.php for the template I can tell you for sure.

Comment: Hello, Brent. Thanks for taking your time to answer my question.  I already have a drop down menu that I've been using for a while (swMenuFree) and does the job pretty well. The thing is, this template has plenty of positions, but there's no actual position where I can put a module in the top of those images: Here's a picture - http://img37.imageshack.us/f/previewtemplate.jpg/ as you can see there's no position to that upper top menu.

Comment: Thanks again, Brent. I'm not really confortable with php/html, I can only edit basic things, such as replacing images. Here's the Template's code: http://www.2shared.com/document/cBFSSW5k/html_code_temp.html

Comment: Perfect, that's what I needed. From the look of the index.php file there should be a parameter in the template config where you select the menu to use. After logging in to the admin go to Extensions > Template Manager > Everhest. The default menu name if you don't pick one appears to be mainmenu.

Comment: Here's the preview of the template config - http://img19.imageshack.us/i/templateprev.jpg/ As you can see doesn't seem to be possible to change anything related to the menu assignment.

Comment: In that case it is going to use the menu called mainmenu. Make sure you have one with that name, it should load automatically.

Comment: Thanks so much Brent! It worked so easily that you should've seen my face, haha! Wish I could vote you up, but requires a level 15 in reputation. Thanks once again Brent!